# How I can hide "0" labels on Y and X axis in ZedGraph?

Tags: c#, charts, drawing, zedgraph

Here's what I am talking about:

[image: The image]

Is there a way to hide that "0" labels on Y and X axis?

I'm using ZedGraph.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try setting this option in your zedGraphControl:

```
zgcGraph.GraphPane.XAxis.Scale.IsSkipCrossLabel = true;
zgcGraph.GraphPane.YAxis.Scale.IsSkipCrossLabel = true;
```

This should be responsible for whether you see a label at the "cross", in your case - the "0" label.
Make sure you refresh the control after setting this, sometimes ZedGraph is picky about actually displaying what you set it to.

Optionally, to remove ALL labels, try

```
zgcGraph.GraphPane.XAxis.Scale.IsVisible = false;
zgcGraph.GraphPane.YAxis.Scale.IsVisible = false;
```